# Validation across two forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a signup process that has two signup forms, depending on whether you are an individual or company, both get posted to the same model (User with devise). I am setting up my validations within the model, but was wondering how I would go about setting validations for the input fields that differ on each form.

For example :company_no is only on the company sign up form, but if I add a validation for this field the individual signup form will fail and throw an error on the :company_no field

I have set these links up to take the user to the correct form

```
<p><%= link_to 'Sign Up as Individual', new_user_registration_path %></p>
<p><%= link_to 'Sign Up as Vets/Rescue Centre', new_user_registration_path(organization: true) %></p>
```

View

```
<% if params[:organization] %>
 <%= render 'shared/company_signup_form' %>
<% else %>
 <%= render 'shared/individual_signup_form' %>
<% end %>
```

An example of a simple validation I am trying to use

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :company_no, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is make use of rails [**`conditional validation`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) and do something like this:

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :company_no, presence: true, if: :record_is_company?

  def record_is_company?
    # check for some field which distinguish between a user and company
  end
end
```

**Update:**

As **@Dave** pointed out *if there are multiple validations to check then either you can make non-persisted model or instead of using rails validation methods you can make [`two custom validation methods`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) and then utilize [`validation errors`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors) to add error, so your user model will be something like this:*

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :company_account, if: :record_is_company?
  validate :user_account, if: :record_is_user?

  def company_account
    # validate company form fields and add error
  end

  def user_account
    # validate user form fields and add error
  end

  def record_is_company?
    # check for some field which distinguish between a user and company
  end

  def record_is_user?
    # check for some field which distinguish between a user and company
  end
end
```

**Update:** 
I instead of checking for database fields for condition. It'll be better if we use a virtual attribute and set it in form(as you suggested in you comment)

```
attr_accessor :company_form
validates :company_name, presence: true, if: :record_is_company? 

def record_is_company?
  true if company_form 
end
```

Comment: thank you, so if i have a hidden field company_form, value: :true, within record_is_company? method would i just put company_form ?

Comment: @Richlewis yeah that should do it but instead of adding an additional hidden field you can also check for field which is different for user and company. I don't know about your database fields but there must be a way by which you would have been distinguishing whether it's a user record or a company record so you can check for that

Comment: well :company_name is unique to the company sign up form, so have tried validates :company_name, presence: true, if: :record_is_company? def record_is_company? company_name end, but this doesnt seem to be working as the error message is being thrown for each form

Comment: @Richlewis that's because when company_name is nil your conditional method doesn't return anything so your validation doesn't get fired. Updating my answer

Comment: @Richlewis yeah you were right. we'll have to make a virtual attribute and then set it as a hidden field. Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple solutions.

One trivial one is to use conditional validation, but this gets messy.

IMO the cleanest is to use non-persisted models, one for each form, and create the user model from them.

This isolates the persisted (domain) model from the form representation. Since Rails advocates putting validations on the model, without an easy way to separate contexts, creating form models is sometimes  quite a bit less hassle and maintenance than trying to conditionalize everything. This is especially true when it's more than one or two conditions.